# cscope function / context <<unknown>>

Tags: vim, kernel, ctags, cscope

I'm working on some kernel code, editing with vim 8 supported by cscope.

Running `cscope -d` allows me to search for symbols, and shows me the expected information including the filename, function name, and relevant line.

However, within vim,`:cscope find s` produces a list of results with only the filename and line, where the function name (or context) is listed as **<< unknown >>**.

In both cases, I'm using a **cscope.out** database in the current directory. **$CSCOPE_DB** is unset.

Any ideas why running cscope from vim would strip away the function context info?

Edit:
After rebuilding the db a few times, I've noticed that `find -s` queries now report the expected context. `find t` queries still report **<< unknown >>**.

Comment: `cscope.files` is the list of files scanned by cscope. The actual database is called `cscope.out`.

Comment: thanks; typo fixed